# Is it possible to get Selenium IDE to run the whole test suite even though errors are encountered

Tags: selenium-ide

We often use test suites to ensure we start from a known, working situation.

In this case, we want the whole test suite to run to test all the pages. If some fail, we still want the other tests to run.

The test suite seems to stop the moment it finds an error in one of the tests.

Can it be set-up to keep going and run all the tests, irrespective of results?

Comment: Do you run them directly form Selenium IDE?

Comment: Yes - we load the whole test suite script and run it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check you are using Verify and not Assert. Assert will STOP your system
2. Each test case restart from a fixed point (like load base URL)
3. Set your timeout (how long you want the system to wait before moving on)